# Travelling with prescription ADHD medication to Cyprus

Tags: uk, health, cyprus

I have an ADHD diagnosis and a prescription for 15 mg of methylphenidate hydrochloride, which is chemically similar to Ritalin. I have tried to research what the Cyprus laws are around this medication as I know that in the UK it's legally controlled – only legal with a valid prescription – but so far i've come up short.

If I am unable to take my meds for the 5-6 days that I will be in Cyprus, it's not the end of the world, but having them would be ideal. So any help finding and understanding the relevant laws would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a prescription? Make a copy (possibly validated). Or ask a doctor for a short prescription (just for holidays). And take some of them: not too much (so for holidays + some buffer time in case of flight delays or accidents)

Comment: It seems to be a controlled substance in a number of countries so if one was going to bet it would be controlled in Cyprus too..

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi to clarify, i have my meds *now* i'm more interested in the legality of taking them abroad - a prescription that can be fulfilled abroad wouldn't likely be helpful because (atleast in the uk) its a controlled substance and not a medicine they can keep in stock so there'd be a good chance by the time it gets fulfilled i'm half way through my trip